# Cast pandas series containing list elements to a 2d numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Take the following series:

```py
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([1, 3, 2, [1, 3, 7, 8], [6, 6, 10, 4], 5])
```

I want to convert this series into the following array:

```py
np.array([
    [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
    [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.],
    [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
    [ 1.,  3.,  7.,  8.],
    [ 6.,  6., 10.,  4.],
    [ 5.,  5.,  5.,  5.]
])
```

Currently, I am using this logic:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import zip_longest

# Convert series and each element in series into list
ls = list(map(lambda v: v if isinstance(v, list) else [v], s.to_list()))
# Cast list elements to 2d numpy array with longest list element as column number
a = np.array(list(zip_longest(*ls, fillvalue=np.nan))).T
# Convert to DataFrame, apply 'ffill' row-wise and re-convert to numpy array
a = pd.DataFrame(a).fillna(method="ffill", axis=1).values
```

My solution is not really satisfying me, especially the last line where I convert my array to a DataFrame and then back to an array again. Does anyone know a better alternative? You can assume that all list elements have the same length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all list elements have the same length (as indicated), what about using masks and [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html)?

```
s2 = pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce')
m = s2.isna()

out = np.repeat(s2.to_numpy()[:, None], 4, axis=1)
out[m] = np.array(s[m].tolist())
```

Output:

```
array([[ 1,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 3,  3,  3,  3],
       [ 2,  2,  2,  2],
       [ 1,  3,  7,  8],
       [ 6,  6, 10,  4],
       [ 5,  5,  5,  5]])
```

Comment: +1 for using `np.repeat`. But, I do not want to hardcode the length. When adjusting your code to `out = np.repeat(s2.to_numpy()[:, None], len(s[m].iloc[0]), axis=1)`, I still achieve an improvement in run time. I slightly prefer your solution over @rafaelc 's and mine (run time ≻ code complexity). Therefore, I will accept your answer

Comment: You can get the list length with `s.str.len().max()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`broadcast_to`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) to broadcast each element to the desired shape.

```
>>> np.array([np.broadcast_to(row, shape=(4)) for row in s])
```

---

```
array([[ 1,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 3,  3,  3,  3],
       [ 2,  2,  2,  2],
       [ 1,  3,  7,  8],
       [ 6,  6, 10,  4],
       [ 5,  5,  5,  5]])
```

---

You can also keep your code but broadcast it yourself without the `np.broadcast_to` (or `zip_longest + pd.DataFrame + ffill()`) overhead

```
>>> ls = np.array([v if isinstance(v, list) else [v]*4 for v in s.to_list()])
```

Comment: +1 for using `broadcast_to` and reducing the lines of code to one. However, my series has around 7 Mio. entries. For 100k entries alone your approach takes around 5.48 s ± 593 ms per loop, while mine takes around 347 ms ± 15 ms per loop. I need something that gets me better off in at least one dimension (run-time, code-complexity) without significantly worsen the other dimension

Comment: @ko3 I see. Well, in this case, you can keep your code, but make it simpler. I added a second solution

Comment: The length of all list-elements could change. I always will now the length, however, I don't want to change the source code everytime the length changes. Therefore, I cannot hardcode 4. When adding this line to your code: `max_len = s.map(lambda x: len(x) if isinstance(x, list) else 0).max()` I achieve the following run time: `795 ms ± 131 ms per loop`, which indeed is an improvement compared to your first solution. It gets me slighly better off in terms of complexity, and slightly worsen the run time

Comment: But, I think I still prefer @mozway 's solution, it takes only 313 ms ± 19.8 ms per loop and I personally prefer run time improvements over complexity improvements